# Send two params in GET request

Tags: vert.x

I'm pretty new using vertx framework, and in the documentation I cannot see the silly thing about how to send two parameters in a GET request. So far I tried this.

```
    $.getJSON('/user/'+ attributeName + ":"+value, function (data) {
    userListData = data;
    $.each(data, function () {
        $('#userInfoName').text(data.fullname);
        $('#userInfoAge').text(data.age);
        $('#userInfoGender').text(data.gender);
        $('#userInfoLocation').text(data.location);
    });
});
```

And then in server side

```
     router.get("/user/:attributeName:value").handler(routingContext -> {
        JsonObject query = new JsonObject();
        query.put(routingContext.request().getParam("attributeName"), routingContext.request().getParam("value"));
```

But then I can see how `attributeName` not only gets the value of the first param but part of the second, very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably doing it wrong. You can get it as a single param and later split with ":" or have two parameters defined in the url as... /:attribname/:value/... 
Both will handle your requirement